# Does wait(some time) must always be in synchronized method?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, wait, synchronized

I have multithreaded application. Sometime in some thread happens exception for external network reason. I think use e.g. wait(60000) - 1 minute to re-connect.
Should I explicitly put in synchronized method e.g.:

```
public void synchronized reconnect(){
     wait(60000);
................. }
```

or it possible:

```
public void reconnect(){
     wait(60000);
................. }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As Eugene wrote, current thread must acquire lock on object. It is not necessary done by synchronized method. You also may acquire lock by explicit synchronizing:

```
public void reconnect() {
   // some code 

   synchronized (this) {
      wait(60000);
   }

   // some other code
}
```

It depends on that you need to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

It has to be! You must acquire the lock of the Object before you can actually wait.

Cheers,Eugene.